# Using custom fonts when export Google Chart as image

Tags: image, pdf, charts, fonts, google-visualization

We want to use 'Avenir' in our Google Charts. This isn't a problem at all when using the charts on a webpage, [as you can see here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nOX40.png). We can simply change the font after the chart is generated using CSS:

```
@font-face 
{
    font-family: 'avenir';
    src: url('../fonts/avenir.woff2');
}

svg text
{
    font-family: 'avenir' !important;
}
```

The problem is we want to save the chart as an image after it is generated and use it in a PDF that we generate then. For saving the chart we're using the function *getImageURI()*, but in the image that is saved the 'default' font (Arial) is used, [as you can see here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OMFXi.png).

Does anyone know if it's possible to use a custom font when setting up a Google Chart like the way Arial is set in the example below?

```
var oOptions = 
{
    vAxis: 
    {
        textStyle:  
        {
            color: '#2a292e',
            fontName: 'Arial',
            fontSize: 24
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

rather than applying css to the chart elements, add the `fontName` to the chart options

this will translate to the image

the following working snippet uses a custom font from google

from the google "font picker"...

> `<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Bahiana" rel="stylesheet">`
>
> Specify in CSS
>   Use the following CSS rules to specify these families:
>
> `font-family: 'Bahiana', cursive;`

in the chart options, the `fontName` is set as...

`fontName: "'Bahiana', cursive"`

---

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: drawChart,
  packages:['corechart']
});

function drawChart() {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Genre', 'Fantasy & Sci Fi', 'Romance', 'Mystery/Crime', 'General',
     'Western', 'Literature', { role: 'annotation' } ],
    ['2010', 10, 24, 20, 32, 18, 5, ''],
    ['2020', 16, 22, 23, 30, 16, 9, ''],
    ['2030', 28, 19, 29, 30, 12, 13, '']
  ]);

  var options = {
    width: 800,
    height: 600,
    bar: { groupWidth: '75%' },
    isStacked: true,

    legend: {
      position: 'top',
      maxLines: 3,
      textStyle: {
        color: '#2a292e',
        fontName: "'Bahiana', cursive",
        fontSize: 40
      }
    },
    hAxis:  {
      textStyle: {
        color: '#2a292e',
        fontName: "'Bahiana', cursive",
        fontSize: 24
      }
    },
    vAxis:  {
      textStyle: {
        color: '#2a292e',
        fontName: "'Bahiana', cursive",
        fontSize: 24
      }
    }
  };


  var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));

  google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'ready', function () {
    document.getElementById('image_div').innerHTML = '<img alt="Chart" src="' + chart.getImageURI() + '">';
  });

  chart.draw(data, options);
};
```

```css
div {
  padding: 4px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Bahiana">
<div>CHART</div>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
<div>IMAGE</div>
<div id="image_div"></div>
```